# UnitTests - Moq - How to Return() object from Moq that matches Parameter in Setup()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I am confused in Moq and I'm not sure what is wrong here.

I would like to test LeadService that depend on ILeadStorageService, and I want to configure Moq in that way - Return the object that matches the GUID passed in Setup.

The problem is in the Moq Setup/Returns line, because when I substitute dependent object to its real instantiation - Test passes, but it is totally wrong. I don't want to test just LeadService, not a dependent storage.

```
    public LeadService( IConfigurationDbContext configurationDbContext, 
                        ILeadStorageService leadStorageService,
                        ILeadDeliveryService deliveryService)
    {
        this.configurationDbContext = configurationDbContext;
        this.leadStorageService = leadStorageService;
        this.deliveryService = deliveryService;

    }
```

Tested method

```
        public TestLeadResponse ProcessTestLead(TestLeadRequest request)
        {
        var response = new TestLeadResponse()
        {
            Status = TestLeadStatus.Ok
        };

        try
        {
            var lead = leadStorageService.Get(request.LeadId);
            if (lead == null)
            {
                throw new LeadNotFoundException(request.LeadId);
            }

            var buyerContract =
                configurationDbContext.BuyerContracts.SingleOrDefault(bc => bc.Id == request.BuyerContractId);
            if (buyerContract == null)
            {
                throw new BuyerContractNotFoundException(request.BuyerContractId);
            }

            response.DeliveryEntry = deliveryService.DeliverLead(lead, buyerContract);
        }
        catch (LeadNotFoundException e)
        {
            response.Status = TestLeadStatus.LeadNotFound;
            response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
        }
        catch (BuyerContractNotFoundException e)
        {
            response.Status = TestLeadStatus.BuyerContractNotFound;
            response.StatusDescription = e.Message;
        }

        return response;
    }
```

then in test preparation:

```
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _leadIdStr = "2c3ac0c0-f0c2-4eb0-a55e-600ae3ada221";

        _dbcontext = new ConfigurationDbContext();
        _lead = PrepareLeadObject();
        _buyerContract = PrepareBuyerContractObject(Id : 1, BuyerContractId :  1, BuyerTag: "GAME");
        _leadDeliveryMock = new Mock<ILeadDeliveryService>();
        _leadStorageMock = new Mock<ILeadStorageService>();
        _leadStorageService = new LeadStorageService("LeadGeneration_Dev");

    }

    private Lead PrepareLeadObject()
    {
        var lead = new Lead() {CountryId = 1, Country = "NL", Id = Guid.Parse(_leadIdStr)};
        return lead;

    }
```

and the test itself:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void LeadServiceTest_ProcessTestLeadWithWrongBuyerContractIDThrowsBuyerContractNotFoundException()
    {
        _leadDeliveryMock
            .Setup(methodCall => methodCall.DeliverLead(_lead, _buyerContract))
            .Returns<LeadDeliveryEntry>((r) => PrepareLeadDeliveryEntry());

        // here is the problem!!!!
        _leadStorageMock.Setup(mc => mc.Get(_leadId)).Returns((Lead l) => PrepareLeadObject());

        //if i change to real object - test passes
        //_service = new LeadService(_dbcontext, _leadStorageService, _leadDeliveryMock.Object);
        _service = new LeadService(_dbcontext, _leadStorageMock.Object, _leadDeliveryMock.Object);

        var response = _service.ProcessTestLead(new TestLeadRequest() { BuyerContractId = int.MaxValue, LeadId = _leadId });

        Assert.IsNotNull(response);
        Assert.AreEqual(response.Status, TestLeadStatus.BuyerContractNotFound);

    }
```

Instead of expected Return - I got an exception: 
[image: ArgumentException]

What I am missing in _leadStorageMock.Setup().Returns() ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Returns` extension method accepts a delegate with same parameters as the method which you are mocking. And those arguments will be passed to delegate during invocation of mocked method. So instead of `Lead` object, you will get the argument which is passed to `mc.Get` method - the lead id:

```
_leadStorageMock.Setup(mc => mc.Get(_leadId))
      .Returns((Guid leadId) => PrepareLeadObject());
```

Check [QuickStart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#methods) section related to accessing invocation *arguments* when returning a value.

---

Note that there is a bunch of `Returns` extension methods which accept a value function as an argument:

```
Returns<T>(Func<T, TResult> valueFunction);
Returns<T1, T2>(Func<T1, T2, TResult> valueFunction);
Returns<T1, T2, T3>(Func<T1, T2, T3, TResult> valueFunction);
// etc
```

As you can see those value functions calculate the value to return from mocked method, but they all receive a different number of arguments (up to 16). Those arguments will exactly match arguments of the method you are mocking and they will be passed to the `valueFunction` during invocation of the mocked method. So if you are mocking some function with two arguments, then corresponding extension should be used:

```
mock.Setup(m => m.Activate(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<bool>())
    .Returns((int i, bool b) => b ? i : 0); // Func<T1, T2, TResult>
```

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't so obvious.